# Retrieve Fragment from Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm currently trying to instantiate fragments from navigation drawer. The problem is that in the past I was able to do that by:

```
MyFragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByid(R.id.fragmentId);
```

But now in AndroidX support library the whole thing has changed and now I don't  know how to retrieve Fragments from NavController, NavigationUI, or whatever. I Need to instantiete my Fragments so I can implement interfaces on those fragments from MainActivity, in order to communicate the fragments between them.

I'm using NavigationDrawer activity template from Android Studio 3.5.1

Comment: I've solved the problem of fragments communication by using shared ViewModels, not using interfaces. I think leaving Activity out of communication is not a bad idea at all, and saved me time and coding. I have followed the example in [this](https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-viewmodel/) post

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just ensure all your fragments now in latest library with Android X. And later, just use next:

```
MyFragment fragment = getFragmentManager()
      .findFragmentByid(R.id.fragmentId);
```

Comment: The Container is not a Framelayout, but a <fragmet> when using getFragmentManager()
      .findFragmentByid(R.id.fragmentId); i get the error incompatible data types

Answer (score 0):

When using Navigation and a `NavHostFragment`, your Fragments are child fragments of the `NavHostFragment` in your layout.

```
Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
    R.id.nav_host_fragment); // Whatever your ID in your layout is
FragmentManager childFragmentManager = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
// Now you can get your Fragment from the childFragmentManager
MyFragment fragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByid(R.id.fragmentId);
```

However, the recommended pattern for passing interfaces to your Fragments in the Navigation world is via constructor injection by using a `FragmentFactory` as discussed in the [Fragments: Past, Present, and Future talk](https://youtu.be/RS1IACnZLy4?t=348):

```
// Create an interface for what methods you want to expose
interface Callback {
  // whatever methods you want
}

// Change your Fragment to take in that interface
class MyFragment(val callback: Callback) : Fragment() {
    // Now your Fragment always has a reference to the Callback
}

private class MyActivityFactory(
    callback: Callback
) : FragmentFactory() {
    override fun instantiate(
        classLoader: ClassLoader,
        className: String
    ) = when (className) {
        MyFragment::class.java.name -> MyFragment(callback)
        else -> super.instantiate(classLoader, className)
    }
}

// Now update your MyActivity to implement the interface
// and pass itself into an instance of the FragmentFactory you created
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Callback {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory =
            MyActivityFactory(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
    }
}
```

By using `FragmentFactory`, recreation after configuration changes and the initial creation is handled in the same way. It also allows you to [test your Fragment in isolation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing) using `FragmentScenario` (which takes a `FragmentFactory`)

Comment: I setted up the communication between fragments by using shared ViewModels, it seems to be a good way to do this